# Using virtualbox to install windows on an actual usb drive?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I have just downloaded virtualbox, and what I exactly want is to run the bootable installation-cd ISO of windows98 in virtualbox to run a setup and install windows98 on an **ACTUAL** USB drive (the USB drive must be mapped as a primary hard drive -hd0-).

**My questions are:** Is this even possible? If yes then how? Or is it possible using other utilitie(s)? And if windows 98 *can* be booted from a USB drive?

Any ideas/explanations are highly appreciated and please tell me if you didn't understand anything so I can clarify, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

- using a VMDK-Wrapper for a "real" hard disk (e.g. /dev/sdb)

  > VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename usb.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdb
- You can boot and install this device in VirtualBox, but only there. Windows 98 (as 2000, XP, ...) are not bootable from USB in general, so this will not work on "real" hardware.

Why not running Windows 98 only in Virtualbox (maybe virtualbox portable from usb with .vdi-file stored on usb)?